# iOS7 last cell in UITableView section forces full width separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The `UITableView` below has custom `UITableViewCells` and I can adjust the separators fine using this line in the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, kDefaultSeparatorLeftInset, 0, 0);
```

However the cell at the bottom of the section has a default separator that overrides the custom `UIEdgeInsets` that I set.

I'd like **all** the separators to be the same width, is there any way of doing this without redrawing the separators manually?

[image: UITableView with wide section separator in iOS7]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some experimentation I've found the only real solution is to set the `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStylePlain`and set empty footers using:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.01f;
}
```

This will not be a satisfactory solution for some, because `UITableViewStylePlain` does not provide all of the features of `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, but it gives me the section without the full-width separator.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution but I prefer to just hide the default separators and add a 1px view to the bottom of my table cells.

Comment: I have the same situation and it works until I tap on last cell. After tap last separator is again full width and changing it in code `[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0)]` didn't help. Any solution?

Comment: Seems the `viewForFooterInSection` is actually unnecessary. Returning .01f as `heightForFooterInSection` seems to do the trick. No more dangling separator!

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation I've found solution! tableFooterView can be covered separator like this:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, 320, 2)];
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[v addSubview:v2];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = v;
```

Comment: This worked for me! I also returned 'v' in viewForFooterInSection. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `separatorInset` property on the tableView itself, instead of on individual cells.  The tableView's separatorInset sets the default inset, which can be overridden by cells, as well as the inset for the "extra" cells at the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately in iOS7 changing the tableView's `separatorInset` does not affect the separators at the beginning and end of each section. These appear to permanently fill the width of the tableView. Changing the `separatorInset` only affects the middle separators.

Answer (score 2):

Give the table an empty footer:

```
self.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]
```

Comment: I dont see how people dont use this. This worked flawlessly when other methods gave me so much problems