# White Separator Above Table Section Headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, separator

I'm having a really weird issue with table view separators.  I have set the separator color to a dark gray which works great below the cells, but for some reason, there is a white separator before my section header (see the screenshot, above November).  When I set the separator style to none, the line disappears which indicates that it is a separator.  How can I remove this white separator line?

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, 320, 2)];

    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // Your color
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // Your color

    [view1 addSubview:view2];

    return view1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.01;
}
```

Comment: Any way to fix this without view hacks?

Comment: @AaronWojnowski I'm afraid not, sorry. I think this is the only way. I have implemented it in my apps and it works perfectly. See this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117775/ios7-last-cell-in-uitableview-section-forces-full-width-separator

Comment: The only problem with this that I see is that if you scroll part of your table off the screen and then back to the footer, then the separator is gone.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this fixed it:

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
```

I was setting the cell’s `backgroundView`, but apparently the cell’s default color was shining through in some cases.