# Footer view's color always darker than UITableView separator's color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView, I set the separator color like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  ...
  self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  ...
}
```

And I set the color of the footer like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footerView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc]
                                             initWithFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, 320, 1}];
  footerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

  return footerView;
}
```

However, the footer view's color is always darker than the separator's color, like this:

[image]

How do I get them to be the exact same color? Thanks.

Comment: It's not footerView seperator darker than table's seperator. It's table's seperator is lighter than that of footerView. TBH, your footer seperator IS `lightGrayColor` but cell seperator is somewhere between "ccc" or "ddd" ...

Comment: @PhamHoan But I'm setting the color of the separator explicitly in viewDidLoad to light gray.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From iOS 6.0 onwards, you can use the below mentioned `UITableView's` delegate method to change the color of the footer view's background-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    //Set the background color of the View
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the footer is still darker unfortunately.

Comment: This actually works, the problem was that because of retina display (apparently), the footer was thicker than 1 px, so it appeared darked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. The only thing that worked was the solution from this thread:

[White Separator Above Table Section Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330784/white-separator-above-table-section-headers)

Basically you need to manually add in the footer separator 1 px above your custom footer view.

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *versionView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, maxScreenWidth, 50)];
    UIView *footerSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, maxScreenWidth, 1)];

    versionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    footerSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];//Your color

    [versionView addSubview:footerSeparator];
    return versionView;
}
```

The only problem I have with this is that the footer separator seems to disappear if you scroll away from it and then back to it in the table view.